# Want to call Progress 4GL 91.D procedure through Ajax call

Tags: progress-4gl

I want to create web service for my Phonegap Android application which will further call progress 4GL 91.D procedure.

Does any one knowy idea how to create web service for this.

Comment: Do you mean SOAP?  Or is any old web access ok?  Does the Progress application have any existing web access?  (Like maybe "webspeed"?)

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading, there has happened quite a lot since 2002...

Comment: I can say by any mean might be SOAP or any web access. No right now Progress application does not have any existing web access.

Comment: Sorry we can not upgrade. We have to live with this version 9.1D.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

That will be a struggle. You CAN create a server that listens to a socket but you will have to handle everything yourself!

[Look at this example.](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19882)

However, you are likely better off writing the webservice in a language with a better support and then finding another way of getting the data out of the DB. If youre really stuck with a 10+ year old version you really should consider migrating to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upgrade everything -- you could just obtain a license for a version 10 client.  V10 clients can connect to v9 databases (the rule is that the client can be up to one major release higher) so you could use that to build a SOAP service.  Or you could get a v10 "webspeed" license.

Or you could write a simple enough CGI wrapper to some 4GL code if you have those sorts of skills.  I occasionally toss together something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

LOGFILE=/tmp/myservice.log
SVC=sample

# if a FIFO does not exist for the specified service then create it in /tmp
# 
# $1 = direction -- in or out
# $2 = unique service name
#   

pj_fifo() {

        if [ ! -p /tmp/$2.$1 ]
        then
                echo `date` "Creating FIFO $2.$1" >> ${LOGFILE}
                rm -f /tmp/$2.$1 >> ${LOGFILE} &2>&1
                /bin/mknod -m 666 /tmp/$2.$1 p >> ${LOGFILE} &2>&1
        fi

}

if [ "${REQUEST_METHOD}" = "POST" ]
then
        read QUERY_STRING
fi

# header must include a blank line
# 
# we're returning XML
# 

echo "Content-type: text/xml"                   # or text/html or text/plain
echo

# debugging echo...
#
# echo $QUERY_STRING
#
# echo "<html><head><title>Sample CGI Interface</title></head><body><pre>QUERY STRING = ${QUERY_STRING}</pre></body></html>"

# ensure that the FIFOs exist
#         

pj_fifo in $SVC
pj_fifo out $SVC

# make the request
#

echo "$QUERY_STRING" > /tmp/${SVC}.in

# send the response back to the requestor
#   

cat /tmp/${SVC}.out

# all done!
#

echo `date` "complete" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Then you just arrange for a background session to be reading /tmp/sample.in:

```
/* sample.p
 *
 * mbpro dbname -p sample.p > /tmp/sample.log 2>&1 &
 *
 */

define variable request as character no-undo.
define variable result  as character no-undo.

input from value( "/tmp/sample.in" ).
output to value( "/tmp/sample.out" ).

do while true:

  import unformatted request.

  /* parse it and do something with it... */

  result = '<?xml version="1.0"?>~n<status>~n'.
  result = result + "ok".   /* or whatever turns your crank... */
  result = result + "</status>~n".

end.
```

When input arrives parse the line and do whatever.  Spit the answer back out to /tmp/sample.out and loop.  It's not very fancy but if your needs are modest it is easy to do.  If you need more scalability, robustness or security then you might ultimately need something more sophisticated but this will at least let you get started prototyping.